# Filtering through lists in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a list of `%Snapmail` and each `%Snapmail` has a list of `snapmail_cameras` and each list object is of struct `%SnapmailCamera` as

```
  %SnapmailCamera{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "snapmail_cameras">,
    camera: %Camera{
```

each camera object has a key `status` and its enum type.

So this looks like this

```
[
  %Snapmail{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "snapmails">,
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %SnapmailCamera{
        __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "snapmail_cameras">,
        camera: %Camera{
          __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "cameras">,
          status: :project_finished,
```

I want to filter first list on basis of this status colume

- Snapmail

  - SnapmailCamera

    - camera
  - SnapmailCamera

    - camera -> status: :project_finished

in above I want to reject all those snapmail_cameras of which Camera status is `:project_finished`

any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal viable example:

```rb
list = [
  %{
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %{camera: %{id: 1, status: :project_finished}},
      %{camera: %{id: 2, status: :foo}}
    ]
  },
  %{
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %{camera: %{id: 3}},
      %{camera: %{id: 4, status: :project_finished}}
    ]
  }
]
```

Solution:

```rb
for %{snapmail_cameras: cameras} = snapmail <- list do
  cameras = 
    Enum.filter(cameras, & &1.camera.status != :project_finished)
  %{snapmail | snapmail_cameras: cameras}
end
```

Comment: Please, when posting questions, make sure you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It took me 10 times more time to figure out the structure and cleanup it up from the noise, compared to typing a solution. Thanks.

Comment: there is like `[%Snapmail{` ahead of snapmail camera?

Comment: This solution should work out of the box. Structs are bare maps underneath.

Comment: ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Camera.fetch/2 is undefined (Camera does not implement the Access behaviour)

Comment: Indeed, access to `status` field from struct must be done with `dot`. I expected one dealing with these structs for months had already implemented `Access` on it. Updated.

Comment: Okay thanks one last thing we can also remove the whole object where `snapmail_cameras: []` just remove `Snapmail` for the first list? I am accepting answer anyway

Comment: I also know its out of the question but I am just asking anyway :)

Comment: Just `Enum.filter/2` the outcome afterward, or use filtering with list comprehension: `for snapnail <- outcome, length(snapnail.snapnail_cameras) != 0, do: snapnail`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993318/httpoison-post-request-timeouts any chance that you can suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
list = [
  %{
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %{camera: %{id: 1, status: :project_finished}},
      %{camera: %{id: 2, status: :foo}}
    ]
  },
  %{
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %{camera: %{id: 3}},
      %{camera: %{id: 4, status: :project_finished}}
    ]
  },
  %{
    snapmail_cameras: [
      %{camera: %{id: 5}},
      %{camera: %{id: 6}},
      %{camera: %{id: 7}},
      %{camera: %{id: 8, status: :project_finished}},
      %{camera: %{id: 9, status: :project_finished}},
      %{camera: %{id: 10, status: :project_finished}}
    ]
  }
]
```

I believe this feels more the elixir way:

```
def process(list, acc \\ [])

def process([h | t], acc) do
  filter(h.snapmail_cameras, acc) ++ process(t, acc)
end

def process([], acc) do
  acc
end

def filter(
      [%{camera: %{status: :project_finished}} | t],
      acc
    ) do
  filter(t, acc)
end

def filter([h | t], acc) do
  filter(t, acc ++ [h])
end

def filter([], acc) do
  [%{snapmail_cameras: acc}]
end
```

Use it by calling:

```
process(list)
```

Result:

```
[
%{snapmail_cameras: [%{camera: %{id: 2, status: :foo}}]},
%{snapmail_cameras: [%{camera: %{id: 3}}]},
%{
  snapmail_cameras: [
    %{camera: %{id: 5}},
    %{camera: %{id: 6}},
    %{camera: %{id: 7}}
  ]
}
```

]

---

Edit:

as per @AlekseiMatiushkin comments there's is no need to reimplement filter:

```
def process(list, acc \\ [])

def process([h | t], acc) do
  filtered_cameras =
    Enum.filter(h.snapmail_cameras, fn
      %{camera: %{status: :project_finished}} -> false
      _ -> true
    end)

    [%{snapmail_cameras: filtered_cameras}] ++ process(t, acc)
end

def process([], acc) do
  acc
end
```

Comment: which is faster? this one or above one?

Comment: Whether one needs to know which is faster, they are supposed to make a benchmark.

Comment: This is more of [tag:erlang] way. I doubt if makes sense to reimplement `Enum.filter/2` and list comprehensions in this particular case. It might make sense if you were filtering empties inplace, as asked in comments to my answer.

Comment: You're right @AlekseiMatiushkin. See my edit. Personally, I don't like seeing `for ... do` in my Elixir code.

Comment: `Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1` is one of the most powerful Elixir constructs, because it allows deep iterations, in place filtering and cumbersome reducing, that cannot be done more succinct and readable. Avoiding it is not a good signal.