# HTTPoison post request Timeouts Eixir

Tags: elixir

We are using a filesystem written in Go, [seaweedfs](https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs). It's being used a REST API on port 8888 to post Files. The issue we are having is `HTTPoison` timeouts.

We post to a file, again and again, we get HTTPoison request timeout.

Few facts:

- File do get updated on seaweedfs we can see the modified date.
- HTTPoison request response is always timeout
- I have tried with curl POST. `for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do curl -F file=@00_13_000.jpg -X POST http://188.xx.xx.xx.217:8888/everc-dupzo/snapshots/recordings/2019/11/22/09/00_13_000.jpg; done` which works fine without any timeout.
- I have also tried to do it in my local machine with HTTPoison as well but it works fine.

**Production**

In production, we are sending almost 1K POST `HTTPoison` requests from which 10% gives timeout error. mostly on such files which are already present. they do get updated but HTTPoison request comes as a timeout.

The code we are using to do POST request is written as under.

```
  def seaweedfs_save(camera_exid, timestamp, image, _notes) do
    [{_, _, _, _, [server]}] = :ets.match_object(:storage_servers, {:_, "RW", :_, :_, :_})
    hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_upload_pool]
    directory_path = construct_directory_path(camera_exid, timestamp, "recordings", "")
    file_name = construct_file_name(timestamp)
    file_path = directory_path <> file_name
    case HTTPoison.post("#{server.url}#{file_path}", {:multipart, [{file_path, image, []}]}, [], hackney: hackney) do
      {:ok, response} -> response
      {:error, error} -> Logger.info "[seaweedfs_save] [#{file_path}] [#{camera_exid}] [#{inspect error}]"
    end
  end
```

hackney pool is set to

```
:hackney_pool.child_spec(:seaweedfs_upload_pool, [timeout: 5000, max_connections: 1000])
```

The author of seaweedfs has a hunch that HTTPoison requests are not getting closed or being reused.
The author of Hackney suggests:

> http is a request/response protocol so unless a response is not
>   supposed to have a body (204, 304, head) hackney will wait for it
>   until you pass the skip_body option, with_body option or if none of
>   them is passed will wait until it timeout

But HTTPoison don't allow it https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/lib/httpoison/base.ex#L812

I am at quite a dead end with it. Any help would be thankful about

1. How should we do HHTPoison request?
2. Should we just switch to Hackney?
3. Or is there any better way to solve this problem? or any way to get more information about why a request is being timed out?

Comment: Do you think the errors are random, or might have a connections with the parameters that you give ?

Comment: Errors are random. and which parameters? hackney ones?

Comment: I was talking about the parameters passed to `HTTPoison.post`. But since there isn't a correlation between them and the timeout, this will be tricky to solve it.

Comment: Yes its true and I have been struggling with this already at dead end

Comment: Did you tried to implement with another HTTP client to check if is something that only happens with HTTPoison ?

Comment: Hmm I am going to use hackney, but I am also unaware of how to make a POST request with it while using it in Elixir project

Comment: I never used hackney, but checkout [Mint](https://github.com/elixir-mint/mint), it is a low level API, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is network bandwidth and/or latency. Basically you open a thousand connections simultaneously with `max_connections: 1000`. I am pretty sure the filesystem itself *and* the network would not be happy about that. On the contrary, `curl` requests in your example do run synchronously, one after another.

Decrease the value of `max_connections` down to 100, or even less and see if the timeout would have gone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing a request timeout issue here. The default value for request timeout is 5 seconds. You can verify with your logs, it should have timed out after 5 seconds.
You can increase the timeout by providing `:recv_timout` in milliseconds as part of your request.

```rb
def seaweedfs_save(camera_exid, timestamp, image, _notes) do
  [{_, _, _, _, [server]}] = :ets.match_object(:storage_servers, {:_, "RW", :_, :_, :_})
  hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_upload_pool]
  directory_path = construct_directory_path(camera_exid, timestamp, "recordings", "")
  file_name = construct_file_name(timestamp)
  file_path = directory_path <> file_name
  case HTTPoison.post("#{server.url}#{file_path}", {:multipart, [{file_path, image, []}]}, [:recv_timout, 15000], hackney: hackney) do
    {:ok, response} -> response
    {:error, error} -> Logger.info "[seaweedfs_save] [#{file_path}] [#{camera_exid}] [#{inspect error}]"
  end
end
```